# Php Sesssion Não puxa imagen

Tags: php, session

```
 <p><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['picture']; ?>" alt="" 
       style="width:50px;height:50px;"></p>
<p>Bem vindo  <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p> 
<p>Esta Area é segura.</p>
<p><?php echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']); ?><p
<p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></p>
<a href="logout.php">Sair</a>
```

Abaixo a sessão puxa o nome do USUARIO corretamente quando logado, porem a imagen nao é carregada.

```
<p><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['picture']; ?>" alt="" 
       style="width:50px;height:50px;"></p>
<p>Bem vindo  <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p> 
<p>Esta Area é segura.</p>
<p><?php echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']); ?><p
<p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></p>
<a href="logout.php">Sair</a>
```

Comment: Qual é a linha que atribui a imagem para a variável de sessão `picture`?

Comment: Como é definida a variável de sessão `picture`? Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY nome");

// Exibe as informações de cada usuário
while ($usuario = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
 // Exibimos a foto
 echo "<img src='fotos/".$usuario->foto."' alt='Foto de exibição' /><br />";

Comment: Lá no seu código o unico erro é de HTML em uma tag p que foi aberta sem o devido fechamento, o qual não causa erro algum,  veja .....  time']); ?><p
<p><a href="dashboard.php.  No mais, o comentário do MagicHat é no sentido de atribuir um valor a session e não se esquecendo que no inicio do arquivo, primeira linha do php deve constar  session_start();  sem o qual nenhuma session vai funcionar